# How to send the JSONArray to Receiver app from the sender app for chromecast in android

Tags: android, json, chromecast

Unable to send the JSONArray values to the Receiver app from the sender app using MediaInfo.Builder class. I have used the setCustomData(JSONObject obj) where we can send only JSONObject as possible but i need to send JSONArray to receiver app using setCustomData() method if possible, Otherwise if have some other default method or any idea to send the JSONArray values to receiver app for chromecast please tell me.

Thanks in Advance.

I have tried with JSONObject :

```
MediaMetadata mediaMetadata = new MediaMetadata(
                MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MUSIC_TRACK);
        mediaMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_ALBUM_ARTIST, ""
                + singers.getText().toString());
        mediaMetadata.putString(mediaMetadata.KEY_ALBUM_TITLE, ""
                + songTitle.getText().toString());

        MediaInfo mediaInfo = new MediaInfo.Builder(songUrl)
                .setContentType("audio/mp3")
                .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
                // here set the customData {"music":"Illayaraja","album_id":"T0000266","duration":"04:57",....}
                .setCustomData(customJsonObj)
                .setMetadata(mediaMetadata).build();
        mRemoteMediaPlayer
                .load(mApiClient, mediaInfo, true)
                .setResultCallback( 
                        new ResultCallback<RemoteMediaPlayer.MediaChannelResult>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onResult(MediaChannelResult result) {
                                if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                                    Log.d(Tag, "Media loaded Successfully"
                                            + result.getStatus());
                                } else {
                                    Log.d(Tag,
                                            "Media loaded Not Successfully"
                                                    + result.getStatus());
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

but i need to pass the JSONArray values to receiver app like this

```
 "customData": [
  {
    "songid": 236854,
    "songtitle": "Kadal Anukkal",
    "cdimg": "http://cdn.raaga.com/r_img/250/t/t0002491.jpg",
    "lyricist": "Vairamuthu",
    "lang": "T",
    "singers": "Vijay Prakash, Shreya Ghoshal",
    "album": "Enthiran",
    "album_id": "T0002491",
    "music": "AR. Rahman",
    "duration": "05:46"
  },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one idea: 
use a JSonObject to wrap your JSonArray.
Here is an example:

```
    try {
        JSONObject myJsonObject;
        myJsonObject.put("field1", "value1");

        JSONArray myJSonArray = new JSONArray();
        myJSonArray.put(myJsonObject);

        JSONObject jsonArrayWrapper = new JSONObject();
        jsonArrayWrapper.put("MyArray", myJSonArray);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d("Tag", e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but set customData() methods only accept argument as jsonObject. is there any method to pass the jsonArray values in MediaInfo.Builder class

Comment: As @Saeid suggested, create a JSONObject whole one field is a jsonobj. In his example, jsonArrayWrapper is a JSONObject so you should be able to use that.

Comment: how to access this customData in the receiver app?